# Element data-ui-view not allowed as child of element div

Tags: html, templates, html4

When  i  am  trying  to  validate   my  template   in   wc3 validations,it  says  the following  error:

```
--------Element data-ui-view not allowed as child of element div--------  
   <div id="uiviewid" class="page-container"> 
            <data-ui-view class="page-container" ></data-ui-view> 
            <footer-dir id="footerDir"></footer-dir>
        </div>
```

I am not how  to  fix  these  error ,can  some  one  please  help  me.